# Defining an infinite dimensional (topological) vector spaces as the direct limit of its finite dimensional subspaces.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, limits-colimits

I am trying to better understand the topic of direct and inverse limits, sadly only in a topological context ( and not categorical). Namely, I know what is the  limit of a direct spectrum {Y_i,f_{ij}}  where fs are connection maps: the free union of spaces equipped with the equivalence relation of having a common successor.

Intuitively it seems to me we are putting together little spaces in a consistent way, to build a "homogeneous" object which does not shows pathological "discrete like" behaviour.

Hence, I thought of a generic infinite dimensional vector space as a good example, but I have not found such a construction. 
Any help, even with other examples of construction of simple well known spaces would be very useful

Comment: GA good example is that of the so-called *profinite completion* of a group; take a group $G$ and take all of the normal subgroups $U_\alpha$ of finite index in $G$. Define an ordering on the normal subgroups by $U_\alpha \leq U_\beta$ iff $U_\alpha \supset U_\beta$. Then you have an inverse system with connecting maps $\varphi_{\alpha \beta} : G/U_\beta \to G/U_\alpha$, with $\varprojlim G/U_\alpha \cong \hat{G}$.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg this is precisely the kind of thing I was thinking of. May there be an analogous in some particular vector spaces ?

Comment: A standard and well-known example is $\Bbb R^\infty$, which is a direct limit of $\Bbb R^n$ with natural embeddings $\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ for each $m\le n$.